# How to copy files in svn into a new directory that depends on a variable value?

Tags: powershell, svn

I'm currently writing a script in PowerShell which calculates a new tag in the tag directory. I want to copy files from one SVN directory to another directory that depends on the new tag number I calculated.

Here are the lines from the script:

```
$tag = Write-Host "$($svnMavenTagPrefix)$($nextMavenTagVersion)"

svn copy http://tlvsvn1/svn/repos-bls/MassAnalytics/trunk/ http://tlvsvn1/svn/repos-bls/MassAnalytics/tags/${tag}
```

For some reason it doesn't work and I receive the following error:

```
svn: E205007: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found
```

How can I copy the files to a new tag?

Answer (score 1):

The `Write-Host` cmdlet prints the string you are passing as an argument but **doesn't write anything to the output** thus `$tag` is empty. I would recommend you to use a format string:

```
$tag = '{0}{1}' -f $svnMavenTagPrefix, $nextMavenTagVersion
$url = 'http://tlvsvn1/svn/repos-bls/MassAnalytics/tags/{0}' -f $tag

svn copy http://tlvsvn1/svn/repos-bls/MassAnalytics/trunk/ $url
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the last line "svn copy $tag" gives me the following errors: svn: E205001: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205001: Not enough arguments provided

Comment: i still get errors: svn: E205007: Could not use external editor to fetch log message; consider setting the $SVN_EDITOR environment variable or using the --message (-m) or --file (-F) options
svn: E205007: None of the environment variables SVN_EDITOR, VISUAL or EDITOR are set, and no 'editor-cmd' run-time configuration option was found     ,got any idea?

Comment: well the solution to my las comment is adding this: 'svn copy http://tlvsvn1/svn/repos-bls/MassAnalytics/trunk/ $url -m "adding a new tag to the mass analytics tags"''